# How can I able to upload picture using vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to upload the image using vue js.

My html code to insert picture is

```
 <input type="file" id="wizard-picture">
```

My vue js code is as..

```
 <script>
submitBox = new Vue({
el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
   username: '',
   picture: '',

  },
  methods: {
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['username'] = this.username;
           data['picture'] = this.picture;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add/post/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {
               alert("Registration Success")

              window.location.href = "https://localhost/n2s/registersuccess.html";
            }
              else {
                vm.response = e;

               alert("Registration Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
}
},
});
         </script>
```

What can I do to implement the same. This is the first time I am doing a work. I am stuck on the same. Can anybody Please help me to obtain the result?

Comment: pass `e.target.files[0]` to your jquery `data:`

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: Inside your jquery replace `data:data` with `data:e.target.files[0]`

Comment: but i also need to pass username

Comment: does it at least work for the uploading? passing the name is simple

Comment: submit:764 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Vue$3.handelSubmit (submit:764)
    at Proxy.boundFn (vue.js:167)
    at submit (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:9252), <anonymous>:2:335)
    at HTMLFormElement.invoker (vue.js:1732)

Comment: Did you get to solve your question?

Comment: no i didnot get yet.. i need to upload multiple images.. how can it be possible

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Just create a new formData object and pass it the name and file

Change your input to this

```
<input type="file" id="wizard-picture"  @change="handleSubmit($event)">
```

And your methods to this:

```
methods: {
  handleSubmit (e) {

    let data = new FormData()
    data.append('name', 'image')
    data.append('file', e.target.files[0])

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/add/post/',
      data: data,
      type: 'POST',
      success () {

      }else{

      }

    })

  }

}
```